# Can silicone screws safely contact CPU heatsink?

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature, screws

I've recently bought a [92mm Zalman cooler](http://www.zalman.com/global/product/Product_Read.php?Idx=848) in order to replace my dead CPU fan without changing the heatsink.

It comes with silicone pins like these

[image: pins image]

**Is it safe for them to come in direct contact with the heatsink?**

I mean, it can be quite hot and I've not found any info about the maximum allowed temperature of screws.

**UPD:** Just in case it's relevant, judging by the [info on CPUWorld](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-Phenom%20II%20X6%201100T%20Black%20Edition%20-%20HDE00ZFBK6DGR%20%28HDE00ZFBGRBOX%29.html) my CPU `Maximum operating temperature` is `62°C`

Comment: Yup, they make silicone baking pans these days, pretty tough stuff.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine. Zalman is pretty reputable and I have used their products in the past.

Similar silicon pins have a operating range of:

> Normal Operating Temperature Range    -20°C to +70°C

As stated on these specs (of similar pins)[Acousti Ultra Soft](http://www.quietpc.com/afm02b-group)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should email Zalman with question about NOTR of their pins. Also, I've added into about max CPU temperature by the CPUWorld info.

Comment: I think the make up of the product is similar. Reputable companies would do qc test to push product to fail to see just how much (heat in this case) it would take to kill it. Your CPU would shut down from over heating before the pins would melt on the heat sink. But, you can always check with Zalman